# How to merge multiple NETCDF file into one?

Tags: time, merge, series, netcdf

I have downloaded monthly soil moisture data from GLDAS in NETCDF format. Each file contains data for multiple variables of an individual month. I want to extract soil moisture data from each file and merge them into one file. So that I can get a time series data of soil moisture data for every month. Here I am attaching 3 links of individual month data for your reference.  (I am working on MATLAB)

https://hydro1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/GLDAS/GLDAS_NOAH025_M.2.1/2000/GLDAS_NOAH025_M.A200012.021.nc4
https://hydro1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/GLDAS/GLDAS_NOAH025_M.2.1/2001/GLDAS_NOAH025_M.A200101.021.nc4
https://hydro1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/GLDAS/GLDAS_NOAH025_M.2.1/2001/GLDAS_NOAH025_M.A200102.021.nc4

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in Linux or macOS, this can be done very easily with CDO:

```
cdo mergetime *infiles.nc mergedfile.nc
```